# [Rx.js]when does Zip operator emit error?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am learning [Rx.js](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) and have one problem with `zip` operator:

```
    var error =Rx.Observable.throw('Oop!');
    var age$ = Rx.Observable.concat(Rx.Observable.of(21,22,23),error);
    var sex$ = Rx.Observable.of("male","male","female","female");
    var name$ = Rx.Observable.of("jack","john","james","lucy");
    var example = Rx.Observable.zip(age$,sex$,name$,(age,sex,name)=>{ return {age,sex,name} });
```

and i subscribe the `example` source and print some message:

```
    example.subscribe({
        next: (value) => { console.log(value); },
        error: (err) => { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
        complete: () => { console.log('complete'); }
    });
```

the out put is not what i expected:

```
{age:21,sex:"male",name:"jack"}
{age:22,sex:"male",name:"john"}
{age:23,sex:"female",name:"james"}
error
```

but just one line `with no value output`:

```
    error
```

read the [offical doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) but no chapter explained when the `zip` operator emit `error`.

Can anyone help?thx very much.

Comment: Here is more info about [zip]http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: hey thanks . I will check this document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see the error straight away because the first observable that you pass emits its values synchronously. (The other observables emit their values synchronously, too, but that does not matter in this scenario.)

`zip` subscribes to the passed observables one by one and in the order in which they are passed. Upon subscribing to the first observable, `zip` synchronously receives all of the observable's values and the concatenated error. It then emits its own error and is done.

If you specify the optional scheduler argument - so that the observables emit their values asynchronously - you will see the behaviour you were expecting:

```js
var age$ = Rx.Observable.concat(
  Rx.Observable.of(21, 22, 23, Rx.Scheduler.async),
  Rx.Observable.throw("Oop!", Rx.Scheduler.async)
);

var sex$ = Rx.Observable.of(
  "male", "male", "female", "female",
  Rx.Scheduler.async
);

var name$ = Rx.Observable.of(
  "jack", "john", "james", "lucy",
  Rx.Scheduler.async
);

var zipped$ = Rx.Observable.zip(
  age$, sex$, name$,
  (age, sex, name) => ({ age, sex, name })
);
zipped$.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log(value),
  (error) => console.log(error),
  () => console.log("complete")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks very much.But i still think this behavior is **weird** because i think in most senarior people wish to have 3 value output.

Comment: Yeah, synchronous observables can be surprising/weird. Added an example to show that async observables behave as you were expecting.