# Angular 5 two failed http call only trigger catchError once

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `Observable.zip` to handle several observables in parallel.

```
Observable.zip(observable1, observable2).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => doStuff())
```

Here `observable1` and `observable2` are http requests, and I have an interceptor catching errors.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoggerService } from '../../core/log/logger.service';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private logger: LoggerService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(req)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError())
            );
    }

    private handleError() {
        return (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                this.logger.error(`status: ${err.status}, ${err.statusText}`);
            }
            return Observable.throw(err);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I did not launch the server, so two http calls both failed, but I found that `handleError` only triggered once.

Is there any fix?

Comment: Interceptors are called for each request so if you know that `catchError` is called just once the problem is going to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your observables as arguments to `zip`. Please note `zip` subscribes to the passed observables one by one and in the order in which they are passed. If first subscription ends in error quick enough before second observable is subscribed, second subscription will not happen anymore. Therefore only one http call is triggered thus your interceptor is intercepting only once.

I learned the above mentioned behavior of `zip`, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196044/rx-jswhen-does-zip-operator-emit-error) by cartant.

Comment: Oh, `import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';` + `Observable.throw(err, async)` works well!